# Removing \dev\nul on Windows

Tags: windows

Something (I'm not sure what) created a directory and file named `\dev\nul` on my C: drive. With a `dir` command, it appears to be a normal file with a size of 949 bytes, but interestingly, with another file utility it looks like this:

```
[a-----]  2-25-2014 23:56:38  949   \\.\nul
```

If I try to do `del \dev\nul` I get this:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Same results with `rd \dev /s`. If I use my file utility, I get this:

```
-rm  \\.\nul...FAILED: The parameter is incorrect.
```

Deleting it from an Explorer window yields the same error.

Although it appears to be harmless, I find it annoying and want it gone. Does anyone know how to make this file go away?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/282194/how-do-i-remove-a-file-named-nul-on-windows?rq=1 a file or folder the solution is the same.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks. Not sure how I missed that one in my search, but I'm flagging my own post as a dup.