# Can't delete a folder win 10

Tags: windows-10, file-permissions

I have a folder on my desktop called con.

```
15/02/2016  11:29    <DIR>          con
```

I cannot open it

[image: unopenable folder]

I have tried the following

1. run cmd as administrator
2. kill explorer.exe
3. rmdir con

> `C:\Users\sean\Desktop>rmdir con /s`
>
> con, Are you sure (Y/N)? Y
>
> Access is denied.

4. Set the security settings

[image: security settings]

The only option remaining that I have seen is to use a gparted on a linux distribution. However, there must be a way to do it in windows?

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to delete an unopenable and undeletable folder in Winodws 10?

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448438/windows-and-renaming-folders-the-con-issue).

Comment: If you don't mind using an alternate OS, you can boot up into Ubuntu and use the provided file manager to remove it from the disk Windows is installed on. It should be gone when you reboot

Comment: [How to Delete a File that Contains the "CON" Substring?](https://superuser.com/q/1275452/241386), [How do I remove a file named "NUL" on Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/282194/241386)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Source: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-files/a-folder-that-refused-to-be-deleted-invalid-file/a8506e19-d623-4af0-ab19-0fd17a672a3a

Solution quote modified to suit your folder location

> Solution
>   You can remove this using the command line, but will want to reference the location differently than you normally would (using UNC).
>
> If the folder is C:\Users\sean\Desktop\con, then this command entered on the command line will remove it:
>
> **rd \\.\\c:\Users\sean\Desktop\con /S /Q**
>
> **rd** is the command line tool to remove the directory.
>
> **\\.** refers to the current computer.
>
> **\c:\Users\sean\Desktop\con** is the path of the offending folder entry.
>
> **/S** is a switch that tells rd to remove all subdirectories and files (like the old DELTREE command).
>
> **/Q** is a switch that tells rd to this removal silently (you won't be prompted for removing the contents).
>
> Change the \c:\Users\sean\Desktop\con path to whatever the location is for your CON folder.
>
> This deletes the entire folder and its contents. It may be possible to rename or copy the folder to another name. I didn't have much luck with the rename, but I also didn't spend too much time on it.
>
> Note that although you can use Windows Explorer to browse to the location \., Explorer doesn't let you delete the folder. You need to use the command line to remove the CON folder.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I get the following response: **C:\Users\sean\Desktop>rd \.\c:\Users\sean\Desktop\con /S /Q
The system cannot find the path specified.**

Comment: For some reason the editor has removed a black slash from my answer. it should start with TWO backslashes. E.g. `rd backslash backslash point(dot)`

Comment: Thanks Chris just tried **C:\Users\sean\Desktop>rd/s \\.\\c:\Users\sean\Desktop\con
\\.\\c:\Users\sean\Desktop\con, Are you sure (Y/N)? Y** and it worked!

Comment: The solution that worked needs to be added to this answer or the original question. Makes it easier for users to find answers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
RD /S /Q c:\Users\sean\Desktop\con
```

- **RD** stands for Remove Directory
- **/S** deletes all subfolder and files
- **/Q** deletes with no more confirmation required