# How to remove a file named `con`?

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

I have a file named `con.php`. I tried to remove it through the Windows command line but it returns an error:

```
Syntax for filename, directory name, or volume label is incorrect.
```

Comment: msdos?  Do you mean cmd.exe?  If so try powershell and / or try cmd again with the filename quoted.

Comment: no powershell also did not work, return: `del: Can not remove item C: \ admin \ admin \ config \ con.php: Path access 'con.php' has been denied.`

Comment: Did you try quoted?

Comment: there's no DOS in Windows 10, and [the Windows cmd is **not** DOS](https://superuser.com/q/451432/241386)

Comment: [How to Delete a File that Contains the "CON" Substring?](https://superuser.com/q/1275452/241386), [How do I remove a file named "NUL" on Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/282194/241386), [Can't delete a folder win 10](https://superuser.com/q/1069857/241386)

Answer (score 9):

Assuming the full path is `c:\foo\bar\con.php`, then

```
del \\?\c:\foo\bar\con.php
```

Due to ancient MS-DOS "compatibility" concerns, `con` is the console, yes even with an extension.  This is in a layer above the file system.

The `\\?\` prefix suspends DOS-compatible parsing and hands the rest of the spec directly to the file system.

Link to explanation: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file#win32-file-namespaces