# I made a mistake on Windows with "aux" files

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, filenames

Anyone who knows their way around a Windows machine knows about naming items aux, con, nul, etc etc. Its impossible unless you use third party software or command line.

Long story short: I made a batch file that makes a couple hundred files per second, all of which are named "aux.txt%random%...".

So now I have 600+ files I can't delete. At all. My laptop is dual booted with Linux, but Windows 10 makes the C: drive read only so that won't help.

I'm at a complete loss! I know it was stupid to even try doing this, and that I should've used a VM, but I was just in the moment of testing the lengths of Windows. **I must delete these files because they are taking up too much space!!**

An example file name is "aux.txt29582001129920227490210248486001047729"

Comment: +1,this question is  clear, well worded and hilarious.  This may help http://superuser.com/questions/282194/how-do-i-remove-a-file-named-nul-on-windows.... Another option is to rename the files and then delete them

Comment: @Jedi I used echo to create the files. Example: echo someText>afile.txt

Comment: @Dave That would help, however my file names are at least 150 characters long and wildcards in command line didn't work.

Comment: @JoshM are you referring to the `\?` solution; the Cygwin one should work fine...

Comment: @Jedi yes, I used 'echo %random%>\\.\C:\folder\aux.txt%random'